# $.ajax json dropdown menu items

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to do a dropdown using json.

json:

```
[["a","Apple"],["b", "Berry"]]
```

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({url:'fruit.json'}).done(function(data) { 
    var items = '<option value="" selected>Select</option>';
    $.each(data, function(i, val) {
        items += '<option value= "'+val[0]+'" > '+val[1]+' </option>';
    });
    $('#menu').html(items);
    console.log(items); //shows values correctly
});
```

html:

```
<script type="text/template" id="menuScriptWrapper">
    <select id="menu"></select>
</script>
```

Why aren't the items being populated in to the drop down menu?

Comment: `$.ajax({url:'fruit.json'})` ==> `$.ajax({url:'fruit.json', dataType: 'json'})` **OR** `done(function(data) { data = JSON.parse(data);`.

Comment: @Tushar Thanks. I tried `, dataType: 'json'})` Did not work. I'm trying your other suggestion.

Comment: Just a silly question... do you have a <select id="menu"/> in your page?

Comment: @LucaPutzu Yes. Sorry, I've added it now.

Comment: @Tushar Thank you. Both your suggestions did not work. See Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9es752nL/1/

Answer (score 1):

I realized a fiddle following your instructions, skipping ajax layer for simplicity sake (anyway if your console log shows your expected values ajax should be just fine)

Javascript:

```
var f = function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    var items = '<option value="" selected>Select</option>';
    $.each(data, function(i, val) {
        items += '<option value= "'+val[0]+'" > '+val[1]+' </option>';
    });
    $('#menu').html(items);
    console.log(items); //shows values correctly
};

f(([["a","Apple"],["b", "Berry"]]));
```

HTML

```
<select id="menu"/>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9es752nL/)

Everythink seem just fine. I'd say your problem lies somewere else on the page. I'd double check your menu selector... Check also you do not have more than one tags with the `id="menu"` attribute

Comment: Thanks. This is my actual html https://jsfiddle.net/9es752nL/1/ How can I get the dropdown populated? https://jsfiddle.net/9es752nL/1/

Comment: @Becky: is there a reason for you to wrap your `select` in a `<script type="text/html"></script>` tag?

Comment: Thanks again Luca. Yes, it should be inside the `<script type="text/template">`. Currently the select menu is hard coded inside it and all works well. But now I have been asked to populate the select menu using JSON. Thanks again.

Comment: @Becky: are you using mustache.js or another client side template engine?

Comment: Nope, I'm not using them.

Comment: After googling around i don't find any evidence of the fact that text/template script would be rendered natively in any web browser (in your fiddle nothing is rendered, not even an empty `<select/>`). I think we are missing something...